# Custom Routing Problems

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

Wondering if I can get some opinions on how to handle routing for a web application I'm currently working on. Since it's a fairly complex app with many areas the default routing isn't quite cutting it. Here's the setup:

URL I'd like to have - `/management/assets/course/edit/id`

Currently, we have an area for management.

I'm having trouble understanding how to make `/management/{controller}/{action}/{id}` into `/management/assets/{controller}/{action}/{id}`

If there's better practices please let me know. I'm also looking into the new attribute routing in MVC5 as a solution.

Comment: The other answers are good here...but just wanted to check...why cannot you register `/management/assets/{controller}/{action}/{id}` in your area registration...are you seeing its not working?

Answer (score 1):

AttributeRouting should be the way to go about it:

```
[RouteArea("management")]
[RoutePrefix("assets/course")]
public class AssetsCourseController : Controller
{
    [Route("edit/{id}")]
    public ActionResult Edit(string id) { ... }
}
```

This allows you much more control on your routes and simplifies custom routing greatly when you have deep hierarchies of routes.

To enable it, change this in `RouteConfig.cs`:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    // Setup attributing routing rules
    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

    // You can comment out the old routing if you don't need it, 
    // but it can work in hybrid mode without issues
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

You could leave in the old routing and have hybrid routes and only override with AttributeRouting when needed if you already have a working site and needs to keep it working.

Comment: Just FYI...its not required to disable conventional routing...for majority of cases I think conventional routing works just fine...you can pick and choose the controllers/actions for which you want to have attribute routing.

Comment: Indeed, I was adding that part as you commented. This is especially good if you have a working site with conventional routing and need to keep it working without redoing the whole routing.

Comment: Thanks. BTW, I think your post is pointing to AttributeRouting nuget package from Tim McCall. I think you meant to use Web API2's in-built attribute routing...please edit your post so that it would be clear for other users too.

Comment: From a folder perspective would it be:
Management { Controllers {AssetsController, AssetsCourseController}, Views { Assets { Course { Edit.cshtml } }, Index.cshtml } } Tried to format it so it would make sense.